# using run_id as name of the log file instead of timestamp but run_id is generated during the run

Tags: python, logging

I'm following the widely used approach of naming log file by timestamp. The log file is created in the beginning of the run. My tool generates a `run_id` during each run which is also logged in the log file.

This worked well, but now as the log files are increasing, it becomes hard whenever a run fails and I need to investigate the log files. I'll be notified which `run_id` failed, but finding the corresponding log file is hard as I need to do `grep -inr <run_id>` over all log files to find the relevant log file, which takes some time.

If I could name the log file by `run_id`, it would have been super simple to just do `vim <run_id>` whenever a run fails. But the `run_id` is not know at the time of log file creation and is rather generated *during* the run by a sequence generator in backend database.

What would be the ideal solution in this case?
Should I rename the file at the end of each run? Or is there any other approach I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

As you said renaming the file at the end of the run seems like the simplest solution. You'll just have to watch out for the possibility that the run fails before run_id is created and the log retains its initial name.

If you want you could append run_id to the timestamp if you still want it in the filename.

Comment: yes renaming at the end does not seem to be a robust solution..